# Quantifier notation: $\forall n \implies \cdot$ versus $\forall n, \cdot$

Tags: logic, notation, quantifiers

I'm not sure which of the following two notations is the correct one (or, are both correct?). I've seen both being used by different professors.

1. $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \bar n \colon \forall n,m \geq \bar n \implies \|x_n - x_m\| < \varepsilon$
2. $\forall \varepsilon > 0\ \exists \bar n \colon \forall n,m \geq \bar n,\ \|x_n - x_m\| < \varepsilon$

If I read the first one out loud it sounds kind of weird: "for all ... implies"?!

Comment: It looks like the "implies" is nothing but a way to separate the *arguments* of the *forall* from the next term. Should really read $$\forall_{\varepsilon > 0}\;\exists_{ \bar n}\ \forall_{n,m \geq \bar n}\|x_n - x_m\| < \varepsilon$$ but this looks ugly when there is too much stuff below the quantifiers.

Comment: Personally, I would strive more for reader comprehension than conciseness. For example, I assume ":" means "such that", but there is no logical necessity for it to be there, and if it's desired to include it, I don't see why "such that" needs to be coded in way that is easily missed. Also, $\forall n,m \geq \bar n$ is potentially ambiguous -- are both $\geq \bar n$ or just $m?$ And the use of the 2nd comma in #2 is problematic, since the use of the 2nd comma is different than the use of the 1st comma, which also invites potential ambiguity. **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)** I would use something like  "$(\forall \, \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \, \bar n \in {\mathbb N})(\forall \, n \geq \bar n)(\forall \, m \geq \bar n)$ it is the case that $\|x_n - x_m\| < \varepsilon.$" All the quantifiers are explicitly displayed for those who what to make use of what they can offer (easy to negate the property, easy to classify the logical complexity of the property, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct. 
I suppose your doubts come from a misinterpretation of the first form indeed it should be spelled in the following way (in natural language)

> for all $\epsilon > 0$ exists an $\bar n \in \mathbb N$ such that for every natural numbers $n$ and $m$ *if $n,m \geq \bar n$ then $\|x_n - x_m\| < \epsilon$
>   or more formally 
>   $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \bar n \forall n,m (n,m \geq \bar n \Rightarrow \|x_n - x_m\| < \epsilon)$$

The other form differs in the fact that it hides the implication because it uses a limited quantification, that is a quantification where you impose some restriction.

They are equivalent because generally every formula of the form 
$$\forall x \in A\ \varphi(x)$$ 
is actually a short hand for 
$$\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow \varphi(x))$$.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly intelligible. I'd argue that the first one is slightly better. That might be clearer after saying it correctly in English (after changing a variable name): "for all positive epsilon, there exists a natural number capital N, such that for every natural number m and n, if m and n are greater than or equal to N, then ..." That is, the antecedent of the $\Rightarrow$ is not the quantifiers but rather "$m,n \geq N$".

By contrast, in the second one, the $m,n \geq N$ is absorbed into the quantifiers, which can be a bit confusing sometimes.